# ActiveRecord shows the same record with different attributes depending on how it is referenced

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I'm debugging some of my Rspec tests and have run into something very strange in my DB. Basically I have two models, Invited and Group. Invited belongs_to a Group.

So I have two different variables that are referencing the same Invited record. Theoretically, those two variables should belong_to the same Group record. And indeed, all the ID's in my records all match, except for a single attribute in the Group record is mismatched. Here is some console output demo:

```
[54] pry> invited
=> #<Invited id: 1, email: "purpledinosaur@yahoo.com", confirmation_token: "3460b1f237f0e7cb97eb3a325bd79cbdb0696405", subscribed: false, groups_training_level_id: 1, group_id: 1, created_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:03", updated_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:03">
[55] pry> inv
=> #<Invited id: 1, email: "purpledinosaur@yahoo.com", confirmation_token: "3460b1f237f0e7cb97eb3a325bd79cbdb0696405", subscribed: false, groups_training_level_id: 1, group_id: 1, created_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:03", updated_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:03">
[56] pry> Group.all
=> [#<Group id: 1, name: "Brandi", start_at: "2015-12-19 05:00:00", expire_at: "2015-12-27 04:59:59", program_id: 3, speciality_id: 3, created_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:02", updated_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:02">]
[57] pry> invited.group
=> #<Group id: 1, name: "Brandi", start_at: "2015-12-19 05:00:00", expire_at: "2015-12-27 04:59:59", program_id: 2, speciality_id: 3, created_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:02", updated_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:02">
[58] pry> inv.group
=> #<Group id: 1, name: "Brandi", start_at: "2015-12-19 05:00:00", expire_at: "2015-12-27 04:59:59", program_id: 3, speciality_id: 3, created_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:02", updated_at: "2015-12-20 01:47:02">
[59] pry> Group.where(program_id: 2)
=> []
```

As you can see, `invited` and `inv` are both referencing the same record. Only one Group record exists, with `id: 1`. When I do `invited.group` and `inv.group`, the Group with the right id shows up, but the program_ids are different! I am perplexed by this, and I'm hoping someone can shed some light here. I am happy to provide more info, please do not hesitate to ask.

I am on Rails 3.2 and mysql2 (0.3.18).

Edit to include more info:

I can reproduce this consistently, although the steps are a bit complex. `invited` is generated by FactoryGirl:

```
let!(:invited) { FactoryGirl.create(:invited, email: sub.email, group: group) }
```

`sub` references a model that contains an email. `inv` is later retrieved using ActiveRecord like this:

```
inv = Invited.includes(group: :program).where(email: sub.email)[0]
```

Sure enough, `Group.count` returns `1`.

Comment: Can you please exit your `rails console` and try to recreate the scenario. Also enter the value of `Group.count`

Comment: Could you please add info about your model; because it seem there is some issue with your model.

Comment: Isn't FactoryGirl a mocking framework - why you expect an object created by FactoryGirl to match the one read from DB?  It is clear from your `pry` output, that `inv` and its `group` are consistent with DB.

Comment: @WandMaker FactoryGirl is a data creation framework. It's results can be used for mocking but it has no own mocking capabilities afaik.

Comment: If you go `invited.reload.group` - what do you get?

Comment: @froderik `invited.reload.group` results in the same behavior

Comment: @AnthonyTo - seems to me that it is the `Group` instance your `Invited` references that is changing somehow here

Answer (score 1):

(It is a bit hard to answer this question without more information but I'll give it a go anyway.)

Clearly the program_id is different in `inv` and `invited`. The only way this could happen as far as I can tell is that some code is actually changing either the one in memory `invited` or the content in the database that later turn up as `inv`. The object you have in memory will have whatever content it had when you loaded it into memory plus whatever state you have changed on it since it was loaded. This will often be different from what is in the database.

I would have a look at `invited` right after it is created and also look for changes to `group` instances. Maybe you are changing a `group` reference somewhere in the test. Or you have some hooks that alters the model (a common source of frustration when it comes to rails).